# variable declared outside loop does change when loop is accessed - node

Tags: node.js, typescript

Right now my function will return true when the if has clearly gone inside the loop and should have changed to false like so:

```
private recalculateGridViewBottomToTop = (window: fin.OpenFinWindow): boolean => {
const toolbarWindow = fin.desktop.Window.getCurrent();
if (this.windows != null) {
  let shiftFromRightToLeft = true;
  this.windows.forEach((win) => {
    window.getBounds((currentBounds) => {
      win.getBounds((bounds) => {
        if (bounds.top >= currentBounds.bottom! && bounds.left === currentBounds.left) {
          win.leaveGroup();
          win.setBounds(bounds.left, bounds.top - currentBounds.height, bounds.width, bounds.height);
          toolbarWindow.mergeGroups(win);
          shiftFromRightToLeft = false;
        }
      });
    });
  });
  return shiftFromRightToLeft;
}
```

shiftFromRightToLeft should have changed from **true** to **false** I was wondering why that is not happening?

Comment: try moving `let shiftFromRtoL=true` outside of the if

Answer (score 0):

According to your code if condition goes true for `if (bounds.top >= currentBounds.bottom! && bounds.left === currentBounds.left) {` then shiftFromRightToLeft will change `false` otherwise it will remain `true`

take a look on below example :

```
if(true){
let a = true
  if(false){
    a = false
  }
    console.log(a)  // output :  true
}
```